# I can not access the function in the saga

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga

I'm new to react-native and I'm seeing saga on account of API, but my first test code does not work because it does not pass through the function in the saga does anyone recognize can help me?
https://github.com/Andersonfrfilho/testeSaga/blob/master/src/store/sagas.js

Comment: Why then don't you show your _ first test code_ ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   //takeEvery importar as actions</p>
   //put chamar o reducer
   import {takeEvery,put} from 'redux-saga/effects'</h6>
   //por padrão</h6>
  //sempre chamar um ponto de parada com um arraya vazio
    function* asyncAddTodo(){
        console.log('entrou an funcao assincrona')
    }
    export default function* root(){
        //pegueTodaAssyncAddTODO

       yield [
           takeEvery('Teste', asyncAddTodo),
        ];
    }

       yield [
           takeEvery('Teste', asyncAddTodo),
        ];
    }
    </i>
```